# How to test the efficiency of Exponential Moving Averages as a trading startegy?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, backtesting, moving-average

I would like to know how I can test the efficiency of Exponential Moving Averages when it comes to forex trading. Can i have any papers that point to the efficiency of this strategy?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Exponential Moving Average is a form of Low Pass Filter not a "strategy". The question in the current form makes no sense.

Comment: I reckon the OP means trading strategies based on signals when moving averages cross either other MAs or the price chart itself - like in Mebane Faber's famous paper.

Comment: @vonjd, yes, sorry it was in a more incomplete format. I was thinking of using the crossovers as a strategy for trading Bitcoins and wanted a way to backtest the strategy.

Comment: @user5257: I think you can backtest it like any other strategy, there is no speciality about it really.

Comment: @user5257: How do you do your backtests normally?

Comment: This is a site intended for professional quants, i.e. people who do this for a living. I migrated your last question to [bitcoin.SE](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) (where you actually had *cross-posted*) but you didn't seem to take the hint. I'm closing this question.

Comment: @user5257: Yet you can accept my answer anyway :-)

Comment: thank you, was greatly helpful.
And @chrisaycock, i dont understand how the Bitcoin question and this overlapped? It was genuine question, maybe the form wasn't sounding particular but vonjd figured out what i was truly asking. The find the whole 'closed' tag quite unfair.

Answer (score 3):

Two good starting points are here:

- Allen, Helen, and Mark Taylor. “The Use of Technical Analysis in the Foreign
  Exchange Market.” The Journal of International Money and Finance, June 1992, pp.
  304-314.
- Lui, Y.H., and D. Mole. “The Use of Fundamental and Technical Analyses by Foreign
  Exchange Dealers: Hong Kong Evidence.” The Journal of International Money and
  Finance, Volume 17, Number 3, 1 June 1998, pp. 535-545.